# How do I setup an online contribution page linked to Mogiv?

Tags: contributions, recurring-contributions

We are using Mogiv for our online giving portal.  How can I link my online giving transactions from Mogiv to my contacts in CiviCRM?

Comment: I gave an 'obvious' answer below but i suspect you want something more streamlined then you may need to give more info about Mogiv etc

Answer (score 2):

You can export from Mogiv and import them in to civicrm using an External Identifier to match the contacts, or match on eg First + Last + Email by choosing the right 'matching rule' when you do the import.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly.  After looking at Mogiv, it looks like the data export from Mogiv is easy and flexible so we should be able to get the data in the format to match our contacts.

Comment: Great. so if this was an 'acceptable' answer pls tick it and/or +1  - that way Stack Exchange knows the community has been able to help you.